# Start html5 video within an owl.carousel

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video, owl-carousel

I'm building a males fashion site with a slider that have both images and a video in it. I'm using owl.carousel as a slider. The video is an plane HTML5 video tag. 
I'm trying to start the video whith jquery like this: `$('#video')[0].play();`

It works perfectly when the video is outside the slider/carousel, but how do I start it inside?

[Codepen link](http://codepen.io/legarth/pen/aBOYWG)

Comment: I have edited my answer, Please check it .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just look your codepen. After few tests, I saw two containers with class video-slider with a video tag with the same id "video" inside. (Check with debug console on the render view and the jquery code `$(".video-slide").children()`).

You can start the videoS with the jquery code `$(".video-slide").children().each(function() { this.play(); });` but before you need to find where and why your blocks are duplicated.

I hope it helps

Comment: I'm using your each approach with the each function, just becouse it is more simple (in my head). The dublicate slides is coused by the owl loop option, so they have to be a dublicate. I have removed the ID and usen the video tag instead. I ended up doing this owl.find('video').each(function() { this.play(); });

Answer (score 2):

Created a snippet

```js
$(function(){
                var owl;

                $(document).ready(function () {

                    owl = $(".stage");

                    owl.owlCarousel({
                        autoplay: true,
                        autoplayHoverPause: true,
                        loop: true,
                        items: 1,
                        navigation: true, // Show next and prev buttons
                        slideSpeed: 300,
                        paginationSpeed: 400,
                        singleItem: true,afterAction: function(current) {
                            current.find('video').get(0).play();
                        }
                    });
                });


            });
```

```css
 body {
                background-color: #91a8d2;
            }

            .container {
                margin-top: 50px;
                max-width: 500px;
            }

            .stage .image-slide, .stage .video-slide {
                display: block;
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
            }

            .stage .video-slide > video {
                width: 100%;
                height: auto;
            }
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.js"></script>

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/owl-carousel/owl.carousel.css">

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/owl-carousel/owl.theme.css">

        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/owl-carousel/owl.carousel.js"></script>

<body>
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12">
                        <div class="stage">
                            <div class="image-slide">
                                <img src="http://imyourman.dk/demo/slide1.jpg">
                            </div>
                            <div class="image-slide">
                                <img src="http://imyourman.dk/demo/slide2.jpg">
                            </div>
                            <div class="item">
                                <video id="video">
                                    <source src="http://imyourman.dk/demo/fashion.mp4" type="video/mp4" autoplay>
                                    <source src="http://imyourman.dk/demo/fashion.ogg" type="video/ogg">
                                </video>
                            </div>
                            <div class="image-slide">
                                <img src="http://imyourman.dk/demo/slide3.jpg">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </body>
```

I have created a sample HTML code. 
Please check it.

set your CSS accordingly.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow">
        <meta name="googlebot" content="noindex, nofollow">

        <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.js"></script>

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/owl-carousel/owl.carousel.css">

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/owl-carousel/owl.theme.css">

        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/owl-carousel/owl.carousel.js"></script>


        <style class="cp-pen-styles">
            body {
                background-color: #91a8d2;
            }

            .container {
                margin-top: 50px;
                max-width: 500px;
            }

            .stage .image-slide, .stage .video-slide {
                display: block;
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
            }

            .stage .video-slide > video {
                width: 100%;
                height: auto;
            }
        </style>

        <title></title>

        <script type='text/javascript'>
            $(function(){
                var owl;

                $(document).ready(function () {

                    owl = $(".stage");

                    owl.owlCarousel({
                        autoplay: true,
                        autoplayHoverPause: true,
                        loop: true,
                        items: 1,
                        navigation: true, // Show next and prev buttons
                        slideSpeed: 300,
                        paginationSpeed: 400,
                        singleItem: true,afterAction: function(current) {
                            current.find('video').get(0).play();
                        }
                    });
                });


            });

        </script>


    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <div class="stage">
                        <div class="image-slide">
                            <img src="http://imyourman.dk/demo/slide1.jpg">
                        </div>
                        <div class="image-slide">
                            <img src="http://imyourman.dk/demo/slide2.jpg">
                        </div>
                        <div class="item">
                            <video id="video">
                                <source src="http://imyourman.dk/demo/fashion.mp4" type="video/mp4" autoplay>
                                <source src="http://imyourman.dk/demo/fashion.ogg" type="video/ogg">
                            </video>
                        </div>
                        <div class="image-slide">
                            <img src="http://imyourman.dk/demo/slide3.jpg">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>

</html>
```